# Dynamic routing in Next.js gets TypeError: the ‘id’ argument must of type ‘string’. Received null

Tags: javascript, next.js, sanity

I’m running into an issue with generating dynamic pages in Next.js. I’m pulling data from Sanity, and I think I’ve got the code right, but every time I try load the page I get a type error - “the ‘id’ argument must be of type string. Received null”. The file path is `‘/post/[slug].js’`, so that’s the variable name I’ve used throughout - I’m not sure where id is coming from, or if it’s something extra I need to pass, or if I’m not passing my slug right!

I’ve asked in the Sanity forums, and it doesn’t seem to be an API issue - I’m able to pull data in other parts of the app with no problem. In the console, it seems like the page compiles successfully, but this error comes up when attempting to load it. I’ve tried it with an empty div in the page component, to make sure it’s nothing in the presentation logic, with no luck.

I’ve put the full error message in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jenkshields/5fd178bb7eb8dfdd13f5f11ea851a9e2), and it looks like something with jest or next-server. For the life of me I can’t figure it out!

```
import client from '../../client’

const Post = ({ post }) => {
  ...
}

export default Post

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const posts = await client.fetch(`*[_type == "blog"]{ slug }`)
  const paths = posts.map(post => ({
    params: {
      slug: post.slug.current
    }
  }))
  
  return { 
    paths,
    fallback: false }
}

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const post = await client.fetch(`*[_type == "blog" && slug.current == $slug]{ title, date, link, excerpt, body, slug }[0]`, {slug: params.slug})
  
  return {
    props: { post }
  }
}
```

UPDATE: this seems to be an issue with either play.js or the configuration it uses - trying in a desktop environment doesn’t result in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your file name. the name should only be `[slug].js`, it should be located in `pages/post`. It should work perfectly when you access the page via the URL `http://localhost:xxx/post/pulled-sanity-slug`

Comment: Thanks for that! Sorry I wasn’t clear - that’s the whole path, the file itself is just [slug].js